# How to use Jenkins Environment variables in python script

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, environment-variables

so I have a bash script in which I use the environment variables from Jenkins 
for example:
 QUALIFIER=`echo $BUILD_ID | sed "s/[-_]//g" | cut -c1-12`

Essentially I'm taking the build id, along with job name to determine which script to call from my main script. I want to use python instead so I was wondering whether I can use these variables without the jenkins python api.

I hope the question makes sense. Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you want?

Comment: I need to use the environment variables in Jenkins such as JOB_NAME
to decide which script to call. I have a bash script which gets these variables but I wanted to do this in a python script. How would I get these variables in python?

Comment: see this,http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's what you need if I understand you correctly:

```
QUALIFIER="$(echo $BUILD_ID | sed "s/[-_]//g" | cut -c1-12)"
export QUALIFIER
python my_script.py
```

And in your Python script:

```
import os
qualifier = os.environ['QUALIFIER']
```

or without the shell part:

```
import os
import re
qualifier = re.sub(r'[-_]+', '', os.environ['BUILD_ID'])[0:12]
```

Comment: But would I need my bash script as well as the python one takes the 'QUALIFIER'?

The $BUILD_ID makes the jenkins environment variable available to the bash script. Is there somehow I can make it available to the python script without having to use the bash one?

Comment: You can access `$BUILD_ID` exactly the same way (using `os.environ`) and then remove dashes and slice it in Python.

Answer (score 2):

import os

os.environ.get("variable_name")